# $header from: problem with variable in php

Tags: php, forms, email, contacts

I am facing problem in $header from: with variable when i put the $cname variable in $header from: i don't receive any mail but when i put a $fname in $header from: so i get mail what is the problem please help. Below is the php form code.

```
<?php 
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$cname = $_POST['cname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$interested = $_POST['interested'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
//
// Mail Content
$formcontent="
First Name : $fname \n 
Last Name : $lname \n 
Phone : $phone \n 
Company Name : $cname \n 
Email : $email \n 
City : $city \n 
State : $state \n 
Interested For : $interested \n
Message : $message";
//
$recipient = "demo@gmail.com";
$subject = "Print Pluss Query";
$header = "From: $cname \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $header) or die("Error!");
?>
```

Comment: It's better not to put email addresses that could be real in code samples.

Comment: What is the typical value of `$cname`?

Comment: This is filed of cname means company name.                                                   
````<div class="form-group style-two">
             <label class="contact-form-label"><span>*</span>Company Name</label> 
              <input type="text" name="cname" class="form-control contact-form" required>
     </div>````

Comment: Well, that's your answer: you need to use a valid email address for the `From:` header. Also warning: you need to clean up user-supplied strings, which could be malformed or with malicious intent. And could you please remove the gmail address from your question?

Comment: Thanks Han-Kwang now my issue has been solved